# Python psycopg2 not in utf-8

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2, utf

I use Python to connect to my postgresql data base like this:

```
conn=psycopg2.connect(database="fedour", user="fedpur", password="***", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
```

No problem for that.

But when I make a query and I want to print the cursor I have something like this:

"Fran\xc3\xa7ois" instead of "François" and it cause problem when I want to create a XML document with this. 
I thkink is come from my encodage, but I found any solution. I try to encode('utf-8') but doesn't work.

I have also seen something like this, but its only for mySQL

```
MySQLdb.connect(charset='utf8', init_command='SET NAMES UTF8')
```

Can you help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make sure you're using the right encodind by running: `print conn.encoding`, and if you need, you can set the right encoding by `conn.set_client_encoding('UNICODE')`, or `conn.set_client_encoding('UTF8')`.

Comment: You beautiful, beautiful person - this is the perfect fix. Trying to read data from Postgres - and for some reason the library seems to default to SQLASCII. But fixed now due to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does the value get inserted correctly when query is executed via command prompt?

If yes, then the problem is with your cursor execution.Try `cur.execute(u"querystring");`(The u indicates utf encoding)

If no, then you need to set the encoding type of postgres to consider utf-8. You can refer [character encoding in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/multibyte.html) to see how to set default character encoding for a database, and on-the-fly conversion from one encoding to another.